# How to use my keyword with File handle in perl?

Tags: perl, file

I am using strict and warning for that i am using my keyword with file handle but it does not seem to be working. Following is an example.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "ENTER THE INPUT FILE NAME:= ";
my $filename = <STDIN>;
chomp $filename;

my $filehandle='';
unless ( open($filehandle, $filename) ) {
    print "Cannot open file \"$filename\"\n\n";
    exit;
}
my @data = <$filehandle>;
close $filename;
```

I get following error message:

Can't use string ("") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at test.pl line 9,  line 1.

How can i avoid such warning/error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you assign the empty string to `$filehandle`, so it will be of type string, but then you pass is to open, which [expects the first parameter to be a filehandle](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html). Also, it's clearer to use the 3-parameter form of `open`: `open(FILEHANDLE, MODE, EXPR)`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "ENTER THE INPUT FILE NAME:= ";
my $filename = <STDIN>;
chomp $filename;

open my $filehandle, '<', $filename or die "Cannot open file '$filename': $!\n";
my @data = <$filehandle>;
print @data;
close $filename;
```

Other notes: when you encounter an error, it's better to output it using `die`. That way your program will return an error code.

Comment: Good points.  Note that more idiomatic perl might express it as:
`open(my $filehandle, '<', $filename) or die "Cannot open $filename: $!";`

Comment: @JimDavis: the perils of copy/pasting OP code :) I've edited my answer, got rid of parens.